# Undefined array key error in Codeigniter 4 even when var_dump() is showing data

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter

This is my Controller Code:

```
public function edit_manpower($Manpower_id=null)
{
$session = session();
$db = \Config\Database::connect();
$builder = $db->table('Manpower');
$builder->select('Manpower.*');
$builder->where('Manpower_id', $Manpower_id);
$query = $builder->get();
$data['row'] = $query->getResultArray();
return view("admin/update_manpower_form",$data);  
}
```

This is my View Code where the error arises:

```
<form action = "<?php echo site_url('Admin/updatemanpower/'.$row['Manpower_id']);?>" method= 
"post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/> 
<div class="form-group">
 <div class=required-field><label for="Name">NAME:</label></div>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name" id="Name" value="<?php echo 
 $row['Name'];?>" name="Name" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
<div class=required-field><label for="Contact_no">CONTACT NUMBER:</label></div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter phone number" id="Contact_no" 
  value="<?php echo $row['Contact_no'];?>" name="Contact_no" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<br>
```

When I place the following line at the top of View, the required data is displayed:

```
<?php var_dump($row); ?>
```

The error message displayed is:

```
Undefined array key "Manpower_id"
APPPATH\Views\admin\update_manpower_form.php at line 65
64   <br><br>
65   <form action = "<?php echo site_url('Admin/updatemanpower/'.$row['Manpower_id']);?>" 
     method= "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
66   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>
```

I am unable to find what I am doing wrong. Kindly help.

Comment: "*the required data is displayed*" - you didn't show us this.  The problem is on line 65, is there anything interfering or modifying `$row`  in the firs 64 lines?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't show the displayed data. I have been checking and when I changed getResultArray() to getRowArray() in the controller, the problem is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your $row maybe an Object array.
#std[]